# Django: Do i have to restart celery beat, celery worker and Django gunicorn when new changes are uploaded to production server

Tags: django

I have a production server running `Django` application

Django server is run using `gunicorn` and  `nginx`

```
pipenv run gunicorn --workers=1 --threads=50 --bind 0.0.0.0:8888 boiler.wsgi:application
```

celery worker is run using

```
pipenv run celery -A boiler worker
```

celery beat is run using

```
pipenv run celery -A boiler beat
```

Now i have updated my model and few views on my production server (i.e pulled some changes using github)

Now inorder to reflect the changes should i restart all `celery beat`,`celery worker` and `Django server gunicorn`

or only `celery worker` and `Django server gunicorn` is sufficient

or only `Django server gunicorn` is sufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have made changes to any code that in one way or the other affects the celery tasks then yes, you should restart the celery worker. If you are not sure, a safe bet is to restart. And since celery beat tracks the scheduling of periodic tasks you should also restart it if you restart the workers. Of course, you should ensure there are no current tasks running or properly kill them before restarting. You can monitor the tasks using  [Flower](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/monitoring.html#id8)